# AngularJS Convert a number to date format

Tags: json, angularjs, date

I can provide a small snippet below to explain what I am trying to do, but unfortunately can not share the main code as it is more complicated.  I believe there is an easy way to do this, but it is escaping me at the moment.

I have data being returned (assume a JSON file for now for simplicity) which has a date in a numeric format, but not a date field.  The format is numeric, but is equivalent to YYYYMMDD (20140513 = May 13, 2014).  I have a similar problem with Time being HHMMSS.  Please note, I might also get a timestamp in YYYYMMDDhhmmss. I do know the format of each type, but want to modify the contents to be human readable.

I want to display this as May 13 (or another date format).

```
<li ng-repeat="Schedule in Dates">
    {{Schedule.Date | date:'medium'}}
</li>
```

My controller:

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);
App.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $http)
{
    $http.get('Data/Schedule.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.Dates = data;
    });
    $scope.OrderBy = 'date';
});
```

Sample JSON

```
[
{
    "id": 13,
    "date": 20140807,
    "time": "18:30",
    "park": 4,
    "Home": 5,
    "Away": 2
},
{
    "id": 14,
    "date": 20140814,
    "time": "18:30",
    "park": 3,
    "Home": 2,
    "Away": 6
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can convert the date to a recognizable format this will work just fine. For instance, "2014-08-07" will convert just fine given your sample code. You can tackle this problem a number of ways

convert the date properties to this format when you read back the data from the $http request:

```
App.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('Data/Schedule.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.Dates = data.map(function(object) {
            object.date = << convert date >>;
            return object;
        });
    });
});
```

or, write your own filter that converts the input on the fly:

```
App.filter('myDateFilter', function(){
    return function(input, format) {
        var convertedDate = << convert input >>
        return $filter('date')(convertedDate, format);
    }
});
```

Comment: If I am reading this properly, the code is converting the date element of each row with << convert date >> (my parsing logic to be added) and I could also format other fields the same way as required.  Thanks.

Comment: yeah, I've essentially given you the framework to handle the problem here, but not the actual code to convert your given format to something that angular/javascript recognizes as a proper date format

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're following an ISO8601 format or it's a Date object, you won't be able to use the date filter. My suggestion would be to either change you your data is returned so that it's in the proper format, or write your own filter to parse this for you.

```
<li ng-repeat="Schedule in Dates">
    {{Schedule.Date | customDate}}
</li>
```

And the filter:

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);
App.filter('customDate', function(){
    return function(numericDateTime){
        //TODO: Custom date logic
    }
});
```

Comment: Reading this through, it looks like the customDate filter will then be used instead of the built in date, allowing me to change the fields however I want.  Then for time, I would create another filter to handle formatting it as well, and add it in as another App.filter(). Correct?

Comment: You could use the same filter and just look for time and date in the same passed in value, or create a separate filter for how you're storing time, if it's not stored in that Schedule.Date field.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  This does work, but I am accepting @mbroadst as it allows me to change the data in the main object, which I can use for more things than just this filter. Thanks though for the answer, as it did work to address my issue.  +1 to help.