# Firebase and Angular: How to convert string to date type in view?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, firebase, angularfire, angular-directive

Because Firebase doesn't support JavaScript Date objects, I converted the value of one of my object's keys with `toString()` (I will probably switch to using `getTime()`, but that's another topic.)

Firebase works fine with the converted value, but now I am trying to update the object.

This is part of my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Start Date:</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="auctionToUpdate.startDate" id="txtEndDate">
</div>
```

My input type is `date`, so when I click to update, after going through my   `$scope.editAuction` function, the edit form comes up. I get the error:

```
Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `Thu Jan 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)` to be a date
```

I understand that the value is now a string and can't be applied to an input with a date value. I am new to Angular, so I'm unsure how to convert the value back to a Date object, just for the sake of the form.

I figure a custom directive would do the trick, but I'm not sure how to go about it. I basically want to convert the value back to `date` and then apply it to the form in the input's value.

Note: I believe everything with Firebase works fine. This is just an issue with the view.

Comment: have you tried creating a new Date object giving the string as an input to the constructor?

Comment: @V31 I sort of tried, but I wasn't sure where to do it. I attempted it in the controller, but this problem has to do with the html, so I figured it was wrong.

Comment: `auctionToUpdate.startDate = new Date(auctionToUpdate.startDate)` in controller?

Comment: See this thread where I had a similar problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641645/angularjs-convert-a-number-to-date-format

Comment: This is [covered with an example](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-extending-the-services-firebasearrayextend) in the Firebase+Angular docs. It's also covered [in a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/syuzw9k1/).